# Why my html and js only works on codepen

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the link of my work, it works perfectly on Codepen, but when i move it to my github personal page, it won't work. There is no response when i push my search botton.
https://gist.github.com/Airhaoran/eec810eda0299297a59d83d353d732ea

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Make sure any libraries you used from Codepen are using on you personal page, that's about all I can tell you. Currently this question is off-topic, you need to give us more information other than *"it won't work"*.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in a document ready function.

**Example 1 :**

```
$('document').ready(function(){

//Place all of your code here

})
```

**or optional**

```
if(document.readyState == "complete" || document.addEventListener){

 //Place all of your code here

}
```

This is not present in the github doc .

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

i think Jquery library is missing ,as it is using $(".mysearch").click(function() in your codepen and have jquery library added to your pen.

I think it is missing in your github personal page.

Hope this is helpful for you :)